# Cannot get android project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I have been developing my program on my desktop, and now want to continue to work on my program on my laptop.

I copied (via SFTP - using filezilla) the folder of the project (in the workspace) to the workspace on my laptop.

When I open eclipse, it did not show up.

I am developing for android 1.5.

I have copied over the android SDK from my desktop (both using 32-bit) and got the plugin for Eclipse. I also pointed Eclipse to the SDK

I tried to open existing project, but it will not show any projects to open.

How do I open my project?

EDIT:
"File" => "Import" => "General" => "Existing Projects into workspace" does not work. THe project is not recognized.
[image: IMport existing project does not work]
<sub>(source: [site-hosts.net](http://file-hosting.site-hosts.net/Eclipse-Import_error.png))</sub>

Comment: I think you copy the folder without the hidden files and dirs. Try tar the folder and put to your laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **File** >> **Import...** >> **General/Existing Projects into Workspace** and follow the prompts.

Comment: Then it sounds like your .project file (a hidden metadata file in the root of an Eclipse project folder) was not copied over. You should be able to create a new Android project and select 'Create project from existing source', though you may lose some of your original project settings.

Comment: Thanks. I then had the problem of it saying 'gen' is missing, which I solved with a Google search. (Solution: edit a file (any file) and save it).

Answer (score 2):

In this case you could ofcourse just open the .project file (which is just a plain xml file actually) and add the Android nature as child node to the nature tag:

```
<natures>
      <nature>com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AndroidNature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
  <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

After that re-import your project into eclipse.

Right click the project > Android Tools > Fix projects properties

Kind Regards

Tristan

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be solved by the following steps:-

1.Cut the folder which contains the project and paste it into any folder outside the work space folder.

2.Now try importing the project into work space by browsing to the folder where you pasted it into.

This should solve your problem.I am not sure why this works but i think it has got to do something with eclipse expecting the project to be imported to be outside the work space.